# Add element(Data) to a json file in javascript without node.js

Tags: javascript, json

I have done lots of research before I decided to post this question but I still can find a way of adding an element/data to a json file which is stored locally. I have managed to open and read it but not add data.
Here is what I would like to happen:

before I run the script.

```
{"logins" : [

    {        
        "name": "test",
        "usernam": "t",
        "passwor": "ber"
    },

    {
        "name": "test2,
        "usernam": "chi",
        "passwor": "Chik"
    }

]}
```

and then I really on a button click I would like to add a new element/data so It looks like:

```
{"logins" : [

    {        
        "name": "test",
        "usernam": "t",
        "passwor": "ber"
    },

    {
        "name": "test2",
        "usernam": "chi",
        "passwor": "Chik"
    },
    {
        "name" : "test3"
        "usernam" : "tester"
        "passwor": "tester2"



]}
```

and all of this preferably should be done without node.js.
I am running this through a script tag in my html

Many thanks.

Comment: If you aren't running the JavaScript with Node.js, what are you running it with? WSH? Deno? A browser extension? A `<script>` element embedded in a webpage (with a `file://` URL scheme?)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a local .JSON file you are trying to edit with plain JS.

And the answer is no. Without a server, that is practically impossible.

You can however change it client-side, but that'll just be for you, and would never save anywhere else.

This is all for security, because letting a web page change a file... Could also allow it to delete files, including system ones.

Use something simple like **Node.js** for a backend server that can handle this.

*I'd also recommend [hashing passwords](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=cczlpiiu42M).*